# How to Execute the script only under specific conditions using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have been working on a script where performing a cleaning script for various columns.

I have to process those script if it undergoes an specific condition.

**For Eg.**

```
if flag = 'Not feasible':
    "Process the remaining steps"
```

**Input Data:**

```
name   age   Contact    col4   col5  col6  flag

NKJ    48!   96754789   8886H  AHBZ        Not feasible
Tom    27    98468300   ^686H  ANKZ        feasible
Mike   28@   78915359   3256H  AK9Z        Not feasible
NKJ    48!   96754789   8886H  AHBZ        Not feasible

JKN8    35   96451188   3566H  NK4Z        Not feasible
```

I am looking to process all the cleaning scripts only if flag= Not Feasible.

Script I am trying to use :

```
if flag == 'Not feasible':
  df['age'] = df['age'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
  df[['col4','col5']] = df[['col4','col5']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W',''))
  df['contact'] = df['contact'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

Like this we have several more rows we are executing, But don't understand how to execute only if flag == Not feasible.

while using the above condition like this getting the error: **ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Please suggest

Comment: What is `flag` defined as? Did you want `df['flag']`?

Comment: @MatsLindh - flag is a column, we are looking to execute rest of the script only if df['flag'] = Not Feasible

Comment: use a `where` statement, i.e `import numpy as np` ; `np.where(df['Flag'].eq('....'), your operation, default value)`

Comment: @Umar.H -  i am executing almost 25-30 columns for cleaning all for different purposes, Can't we have a single if condition under which i can process rest of the scripts.

Comment: you'll need to chunk your dataframe into parts, which is beyond the scope of the question. I would suggest just using the `.where` method its cleaner & safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save you effort on amending large number of scripts for cleaning various columns, you do it in these steps:

1. firstly extract those not for processing into another dataframe,
2. re-define `df` with the extracted rows for processing with a copy
3. run your cleaning scripts with original syntax
4. concat those not for processing rows (from step 1) back to the cleaned results (from step 3) with `.sort_index()` to restore their original sequence.

---

```
df1 = df.loc[df['flag'] != 'Not feasible']               # Step 1
df = df.loc[df['flag'] == 'Not feasible'].copy()         # Step 2

# Run your cleaning codes with original syntax           # Step 3
df['age'] = df['age'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
df[['col4','col5']] = df[['col4','col5']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace('\W',''))
df['Contact'] = df['Contact'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)

df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index()                   # Step 4
```

Result:

```
print(df)


   name   age     Contact   col4  col5 col6          flag
0   NKJ  48.0  96754789.0  8886H  AHBZ       Not feasible
1   Tom    27  98468300.0  ^686H  ANKZ           feasible
2  Mike  28.0  78915359.0  3256H  AK9Z       Not feasible
3   NKJ  48.0  96754789.0  8886H  AHBZ       Not feasible
4  JKN8  35.0  96451188.0  3566H  NK4Z       Not feasible
```

Non-processed data combined back to cleaned data.  Original row sequence maintained with `.sort_index()` after `pd.concat()`

Comment: Having a date column When trying to print df1.head, the Date format is getting changed.

Comment: @NKJ  The above solution is independent of what's the extra column (date or others) you have.  It just enable you to reuse your original codes by enclosing something before and after your cleaning scripts.  So, your problem of date column is a new problem unrelated to your original question.

Comment: Yes I understand, Is there any way to avoid getting the change in Date format for df1, Please Suggest.

Comment: @NKJ  What's the format of the Date field ?   String or datetime64 ?   And if string, what's  the format ?  'MM-DD-YYYY'  or others ?

Comment: It comes in all the format, It can be String, MM-DD-YYYY, DD/MM/YYYY, Dont have any fixed one .

Comment: @NKJ  If you have criteria to split the data according to their data source and know the specific date format of such subset of data, then you can use the `format=` parameter of the `pd.to_datetime()` function to correctly parse the subset of dates.  Otherwise, you can still use `pd.to_datetime()`  without specifying format to let it infer the date format.  However, for some dates, you won't be able to distinguish whether 05/04 is May 4 or Apr 5 then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232054/discussion-between-nkj-and-seabean).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to filter using a boolean mask?
E.g. `df.loc[df["flag"]=="Not feasible", 'age'] = df.loc[df["flag"]=="Not feasible", 'age'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)`
Similarly for all the other transformations you wish to apply to the df.

Comment: We are  processing many scrips, But due to large volume of data we only needs to process  if the column flag with value "Not Feasible"